# Reuse last externally executed command in VIM

Tags: vim

In VIM, I want to execute a command (like `:!mkdir src/main/scala/xxx`)
Then, I want to also make a subdirectory of the just created directory.
Can I have VIM retype the last used command and then I append the sub directory name to it
(So I can have `:!mkdir scr/main/scala/xxx/yyy`  without retyping the whole stuff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just hit : then the up arrow to go through your command history?

Comment: Or `:!` then up arrow to go through the commands that start with `!`

Answer (score 3):

```
:!mkdir test
:!!/test2
```

will do what you want, see :h :!. Citation from there:

> Any '!' in {cmd} is replaced with the previous external command (see also 'cpoptions').

// Why don't you use `-p` switch to `mkdir`? `mkdir -p test/test2/test3/...` will create directory with all its parents if they do not exist.

Comment: Thank so much for the awesome tip on `!` and `-p` switch.